# Can you explain the output of the following C code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=4,y=0,z;
    while(x>=0)
   {
     x--; 
     y++;
     if(x==y)
         continue;
     else
         printf("%d%d\n",x,y);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In this code I got the output as

```
31
13
04
-15
```

I didn't understand the output. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use the debugger (`gdb`) to run it step by step and inspect variables.

Comment: What did you expect it to print?  Where is the confusion?

Comment: The first line of output would be `31`, with no space. Either you're not getting the output you say you are, or you're not running the code you say you are.

Comment: Read about 1) `while` loop 2) post-increment(decrement) operator 3) equality operator

Comment: Yeah i had doubts in post-increment and decrement operators..Thanks all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. You only need good understanding of `continue` statement.

- Loop 1 : x = 3 , y = 1 (after x-- and  y++)
- Loop 2 : x = 2 , y = 2 (So you hit the `continue` and goes to the top of the loop again
- Loop 3 : x = 1 , y = 3
- Loop 4 : x = 0 , y = 4 (The loop checks till `x>=0`)
- Loop 5 : x = -1, y = 5 (Loop terminates)

Comment: It should be `x--` and `y++`

Comment: Ok. I will change it.

Comment: Yeah it is simple ..I had doubts in post increment and decrement operators..I had understood it in a different way..I'll read abt them.Thanks .

Comment: As a side note, the continue statement should be avoided as tends to generate spaghetti code, as it did in this question. (A goto by any other name...)

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop runs for 5 iterations and in each iteration, `y` is increased by one and `x` is decreased by one. In all the iterations, `x` and `y` are printed except when `x` and `y` is equal to 2.